# Socket doesn't connect after create a new conection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

At first I created a connection and all the events are called normally as expected.

After end the functions for this connection, I have to disconnect and wait something to happen to create a new connection so I can send the same events but different information, but then `connect` event is not called any more and so neither the other emits.

The `onNewEvent` is only going to happen if it connects first. The first time it works, but all the next tries `connect` event is not called, neither the other events, `reconnect_error`, error and those.

Do I have to keep the connection and just make the emits with the new information?

```
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');

open(1,"User1")
//wait some time
open(2, "User2") // never connects

function open(id, user){
        var client =  ioc.connect(cons.serverSocket, {reconnection: false, "connect timeout":5000});
        client.once("connect", function () { //tried client.on and client.once node is called 2nd time
            console.log('Client: Connected');
            console.log('ID: ' + id + ' USER: ' + user);
            client.emit("onUserLogin", id, user, function (message) {
                console.log('Echo received: ', message);
            });

           client.emit("onNewEvent", cadena, function (message) {
                console.log('Echo received: ', message);
            });

           client.on("onNewEvent", function (emit) {    
                console.log('onNewEvent received ');

                //some functions and callbacks

                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log(new Date())
                    console.log("liberado!_")
                    liberado = true;
                }, 7 * 1000)

                client.disconnect() // the first connection does call the disconnect event
                //client.io.skipReconnect = false; //also tried
            }) 

        });
        client.on("connect_error", function (emit) {
            console.log('client connect_error received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("connect_timeout", function (emit) {
            console.log('client connect_timeout received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("reconnect", function (emit) {
            console.log('client reconnect received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("reconnect_attempt", function (emit) {
            console.log('client reconnect_attempt received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("reconnecting", function (emit) {
            console.log('client reconnecting received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("reconnect_error", function (emit) {
            console.log('client reconnect_error received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("reconnect_failed", function (emit) {
            console.log('client reconnect_failed received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("ping", function (emit) {
            console.log('client ping received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("pong", function (emit) {
            console.log('client pong received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("error", function (emit) {
            console.log('client error received: ' + emit);
        })
        client.on("disconnect", function (emit) {
            console.log('client disconnect received: ' + emit);
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you **have** to, but it's definitely the way you usually work with sockets: you keep them around and just use them to send data whenever the need arises (and most importantly, so you can receive data at any time).

Comment: You mean I have to keep the connection alive?